# C# Selecting Text in RichTextBox offset with new line

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, richtextbox

I have a problem with selecting text in RichTextBox ( WinForms ) matched by a Regex.

The first line is selected correctly, but the second, third, ..., N line the selected text is shifted. I suspect that the culprit is '\n', but I don't have an idea how to fix it.

```
foreach (Match m in mColl)
{
    this.rtbContent.Select(m.Index, m.Length);
    this.rtbContent.SelectionBackColor = Color.Tomato;
}
```

My Regex is [a-zA-Z].

Example:
Test
Test
Test

The first test will be OK, but the secont will select est and the third will be st.

Comment: Are you sure that string is "Test\nTest\nTest\n"?

Comment: Code works.  Need to see the actual text you are using in the RichTextBox control.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` matches 12 times your example, once for each char (`m.Length == 1` for all matches). If you want to match the entire example once: `[a-zA-Z\r\n]+`

Comment: The word wrap is set to True and every time I'm pasting long text the problem occurs. I'm using the first 2 paragraphs of the World War 2 Wiki page. I would provide a screenshot, but I don't have reputation of 10 to do so.

Comment: Post your code for RegEx so we can play along. How did you get the text into the RTB? Can you show the code that populated the RTB?